# Error 500 Internal server error on Post Method

Tags: javascript, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I am posting a JSON in javascript but I am getting an error 500 internal server error does anyone have a solution regarding this.

My code is.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url,true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept");

xhttp.send(jsonString);
```

Comment: As mentioned by others the api of dynamics you are trying to connect is wrong. How about you show us your complete request. Where do you build your url and also your jsonString parameter. It would be good to see that as well. In general api for dynamics will go something like https://abc.crm4.dynamcis.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select.....

Comment: Kindly recheck the url by invoking over your address bar with proper credentials  as _The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request._

Comment: agreed what is your `url` var set as at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is the general catch-all error when the server throws an exception. It is the error message when no more specific error message is suitable. It may be difficult to troubleshoot this error because it can be triggered out by many different issues. Please debug your server-side code, in order to find the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume the var 'url' is the address of the server you want to contact ?
error 500 is a server error and it seem you're currently on client side so if you're the creator of the server site, you should check what you send to it and what you received.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I changed the Method to 'GET' and it worked. That may not be the perfect solution but it can help.